# mixing sound from multiple users' processes on linux

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card

As in the title.

Is it possible without setting up a system-wide pulse server to mix audio output from multiple processes owned by different users on Linux?  I have no trouble mixing audio when all the processes are owned by the same user, but as soon as I attempt using sound in processes owned by different users (specifically, mpd and the currently logged-in user's programs), it goes to first-come, first-served.  Whichever user grabs the soundcard first gets access, and any other user's processes wait until it is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to share an user-mode pulse server among local users via TCP.

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to enable the TCP module. I basically disabled auth to simplify configuration. Note there may be security implications if you aren't the only one using the computer.

> load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1

Restart PulseAudio, if you are using systemd, this can be done with `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`.
Note that if there are already multiple PulseAudio servers running, you may need to stop them. Otherwise only the one that started first works.

Now PulseAudio should be listening on a TCP port, this can be verified with the command `ss -ltp`. You'll probably see something like this:

```
LISTEN     0    0        *:4713       *:*                    
users:(("pulseaudio",pid=3130,fd=31))
```

which indicates that PulseAudio is listening on the port 4713.

To configure clients, edit `/etc/pulse/client.conf` and enable auto connection:

> auto-connect-localhost = yes

This is disabled by default on newer versions of PulseAudio for security reasons.

Next try playing some audio, cheers!

Comment: To `load-module` you can add also: `listen=127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

put this on your `~/.pulse/default.pa` of the current user running X

```
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

Then restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k;pulseaudio -D`

And then put this on all other users `~/.pulse/client.conf`

```
default-server = 127.0.0.1
```

I initially learned about it at http://billauer.co.il/blog/2014/01/pa-multiple-users/, and tweaked it a bit (the include line)

working on ubuntu 20.04

mixed 2 musics from different users

Answer (score 1):

For me on Debian 9 it was like this:

```
# add all your users to the audio group
usermod -aG audio user1
usermod -aG audio user2
usermod -aG audio user3

# pulseaudio config:    
# remove old per-user configs
rm -rf /home/*/.config/pulse/

# common client config
echo '
auto-connect-localhost = yes
' >> /etc/pulse/client.conf

# common server config - only the first one get started on login
echo '
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=127.0.0.1 auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1
' >> /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Then restart, login, check:

```
ps aux | grep pulseaudio
# should be sth

netstat -ltunp | grep pulseaudio
# should be sth

# play sample file
cvlc 'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_OOG_1MG.ogg'
```