# How to hear the sound from other consoles in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, console

I have Linux Mint 17.2. (I know, I will do an update soon). I would like to hear sounds from all consoles even that different users can be logged in there.

My desired usecase is:

1. Open 1st console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login as user A
3. Execute `mplayer my_favourite_album.mp3`
4. Open 2nd console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
5. There is no sound. But I want to continue to listen to the `my_favourite_album.mp3`.

The same for consoles with X server:

1. Open 7th console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
2. Login as user A
3. Open with VLC `my_favourite_album.mp3`
4. Open 8th console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
5. There is no sound. But I want to continue to listen to the `my_favourite_album.mp3`.

Is it possible? How to do that?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "ConsoleKit".

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my problem. I based on [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PulseAudio#Permissions) and [also this](https://superuser.com/a/1103852/189800) and [this was helpful](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat#Multiple_users_on_single_sound_card:_PulseAudio).

The solution:

1. Add to `/etc/rc.local` somewhere high setting permissions always to all users:

   `bash -c '/usr/bin/find /dev/snd/ ! -type d | while read; do /usr/bin/setfacl -m o::rw "${REPLY}"; done'`
2. For every user execute the following to configure his PulseAudio server and client:

   ```
   echo '.include /etc/pulse/default.pa' > ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
   echo 'load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1' >> ~/.config/pulse/default.pa

   echo '.include /etc/pulse/client.conf' > ~/.config/pulse/client.conf
   echo 'default-server = 127.0.0.1' >> ~/.config/pulse/client.conf

   echo 'ps aux | grep "pulseaudio --daemonize=yes" | grep -v grep || /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=yes' >> ~/.profile
   ```

I know there are some sound security issues in this solution, but only I use this computer and sounds in my computer are not confidential.